# Автоматическая высота tbody таблицы средствами css

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то сделать чтобы высота tbody таблицы подстраивалась по высоте окна браузера с помощью css?

[image: tbody auto height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно tbody задать height: calc(100vh - "тут пишется высота thead и других элементов которые так же влияют на высоту окна браузера без кавычек - например 100px");
Если этого не сделать, то высота tbody будет больше высоты окна браузера, так как будет учитываться и высота thead и прочих влияющих на высоту.

Comment: Спасибо! Что-то такое и хотел, не знал, что так можно сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда рад помочь)